# Error when installing ggbiplot r-package developer version from github

Tags: javascript, r, ggbiplot

I encounter an error when installing an r-package (ggbiplot) from github.

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("ggbiplot", "vqv")
Installing ggbiplot from vqv
Installing ggbiplot
* checking for file 'C:\Users\Jocelyn\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEddAJr\vqv-ggbiplot-2623d7c/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'ggbiplot':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'ggbiplot_0.5.tar.gz'
 ERROR
packaging into .tar.gz failed
Erreur : Command failed (1)
De plus : Message d'avis :
l'exécution de la commande '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-214~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD build 
  "C:\Users\Jocelyn\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEddAJr\vqv-ggbiplot-2623d7c" 
  --no-manual --no-vignettes' renvoie un statut 1
```

Do you have an idea for me? 
Thanks !

Comment: Looks like the error was creating the .tar.gz. It appears you are on Windows. Do you have the Rtools installed that are needed for package development/compilation? What does `has_devel()` (also from `devtools`) return?